# ServiceStack PUT validation

Tags: json, rest, put, servicestack

I'm trying to get validation to work on PUT operations using ServiceStack,

this is my client code

```
    var client = new JsonServiceClient();
    return client.Put<string>(url, content);
```

I have validation wired up and working on the server, since I can see the breakpoint hit and validation failing, but all I get back on the client is

```
HTTP/1.1 400 NotEmpty
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Date: Sun, 06 May 2012 17:08:44 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

same happens when I do a successful PUT, I just get plain string back, something is leading me to believe that ServiceStack doesn't want to return json on PUT.

Comment: By default ServiceStack adds its own HTTP Header so you know the request was handled by ServiceStack - it's missing here. Do you have a stand-alone failing unit test showing this error? There's a Integration Tests template that helps create integration tests at: https://github.com/JonCanning/ServiceStackIntegrationTesting

Comment: thanks, I'm just about to get out of the house, I'll try to write a test when I get back.

Comment: Duh. I was returning an object rather than the IHasrespobseStaus object. All fixed now. Thanks.